# OpenGL - Shadow cubemap sides have incorrect rotation?

Tags: opengl, mapping, shadow, depth

This is more of a technical question than an actual programming question.

I'm trying to implement shadow mapping in my application, which was fairly straight forward for simple spotlights. However, for point lights I'm using shadow cubemaps, which I'm having a lot of trouble with.

After rendering my scene on the cubemap, this is my result:

[image]

(I've used glReadPixels to read the pixels of each side.)

Now, the object that should be casting the shadow is being drawn as it should be, what confuses me is the orientation of the sides of the cubemap. It seems to me that the left side (X-) should be connected with the bottom side (y-), so basically rotated by 90° clockwise:

[image]

I can't find any examples of how a shadow cubemap is supposed to look like, so I'm unsure whether there's actually something wrong with mine or if it's supposed to look like that. I'm fairly certain my matrices are set up correctly and the shaders for rendering to the shadow map are as simple as can be, so I have my doubts that there's anything wrong with them:

```
// Projection Matrix:
glm::perspective<float>(90.f,1.f,2.f,m_distance) // fov = 90, near plane = 1, far plane = 2, distance = the light's range

// View Matrices:
glm::lookAt(GetPosition(),GetPosition() +glm::vec3(1,0,0),glm::vec3(0,1,0));
glm::lookAt(GetPosition(),GetPosition() +glm::vec3(-1,0,0),glm::vec3(0,1,0));
glm::lookAt(GetPosition(),GetPosition() +glm::vec3(0,1,0),glm::vec3(0,0,-1));
glm::lookAt(GetPosition(),GetPosition() +glm::vec3(0,-1,0),glm::vec3(0,0,1));
glm::lookAt(GetPosition(),GetPosition() +glm::vec3(0,0,1),glm::vec3(0,1,0));
glm::lookAt(GetPosition(),GetPosition() +glm::vec3(0,0,-1),glm::vec3(0,1,0));
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;

uniform mat4 depthMVP;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = depthMVP *vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1.0);
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) out float fragmentdepth;

void main()
{
    fragmentdepth = gl_FragCoord.z;
}
```

(I actually found these on another thread from here iirc)

Using this cubemap in the actual scene gives me odd results, but I don't know if my main fragment / vertex shaders are at fault here, or if my cubemap is incorrect in the first place, which makes debugging very difficult.

I'd basically just like to have confirmation / disconfirmation whether or not my shadow cubemap 'looks' right and, if it doesn't, what could be causing such behavior.

// Update:

Here's a video of how the shadowmap is updated: http://youtu.be/t9VRZy9uGvs

It looks right to me, could anyone confirm / disconfirm?

Comment: Draw your scene 6 times into each face of a **color** cubemap from the position of your camera, then sample the cubemap like you would your depth cubemap during lighting but instead of doing a depth comparison for shadow, just write the sampled color to the screen. This will immediately let you see if any of the faces of your cubemap are oriented incorrectly.

Comment: How would I actually draw a side of the cubemap as 2d texture inside my shader? Using sampler2D I can't get it to draw anything. With samplerCube I can get it to draw a part of the texture, but I'm unsure how I'd draw the entire thing.

Comment: What you need to do is get a direction vector from the camera (origin of your cube map) to the fragment. Then when it comes time to shade that fragment, just sample the cubemap `samplerCube` with that direction vector and write the color out. If everything works correctly and you update the cubemap every frame then it should look pretty natural. If anything is wrong with your cubemap camera, however, the scene will be projected strangely. And you do not draw it as a 2D texture, you use `texture (...)` with a `samplerCube` and **3D** texture coordinates.

Comment: I'm still somewhat confused. I know that the second parameter of texture(...) has to be a 3D direction when used with a samplerCube, but where do my UV coordinates come into play? This is my shader at the moment (Obviously not complete): pastebin.com/cZpTQkSc

Comment: They do not come into play at all. You understand what a cuemap is, right? It is basically a cube with 6 different texture faces. You sample the cubemap using a direction vector, and it shoots a ray into this virtual cube. Whatever face the ray hits is where the texel comes from. It is of course a little bit more complicated than this, but that is the gist of it.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working. I've added a video to my question which shows the shadowmap in realtime. Now I just need to know if it's actually behaving as it should. (The projection on the world is obviously not quite working yet.)